# If Statment depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, if-statement, screen, media-queries

I have created a JS if-statment, that should detect the screen width and change css properties depending on the screen width. If the screen is wider than 700px, than the #header_menu should be extended. If the resolution is below 700, than #menu should be extended (by clicking the trigger).

All in all the function is working, but only the first time I resize the window. I am not sure what the mistake is ...

Thanks for your help ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('load resize', function checkPosition(){
        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)').matches) {
            $("#menu_trigger").click(function(){
                $("#menu").css('width', '90%');
                $("#closer, #header").css('margin-left', '90%');
                $("#closer, #header").css('margin-right', '-90%');
            });
        } else {
            $("#menu_trigger").click(function(){
                $("#header_menu").css('width', 'auto');
            });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: because i want to change the function of the #menu_trigger button, depending on the screen width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

engages the resize event of the window to a function , try this

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", checkPosition));

function checkPosition(){
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)').matches) {
        $("#menu_trigger").click(function(){
            $("#menu").css('width', '90%');
            $("#closer, #header").css('margin-left', '90%');
            $("#closer, #header").css('margin-right', '-90%');
        });
    } else {
        $("#menu_trigger").click(function(){
            $("#header_menu").css('width', 'auto');
        });
    }
}
```

every time the page is resized, the function will be called

Comment: thanks for your answer! the function is working properly when i downsize the window from above 700 to below 700px. but when i change the resolution from below 700 to over 700 it still enlarges the #menu but not #header_menu. any idea?

Comment: try use this condition : if($(window).width() < 700){..}else{..} or if($(window).width() > 700){..}else{..}

Comment: i found the problem. after resizing something got stuck in the click function. i just added the contrary behavior to the click function. thanks for your help!

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem "accept it", so help the other users :)